# Using XmlParser in archetype-post-generate.groovy script for maven archetype

Tags: xml, maven, groovy, archetypes

Since upgrading to a newer version of maven (3.5.2) my archetype-post-generate groovy script in my own maven archetype has stopped working.
It has trouble to create a new XMLParser (new XmlParser()). Seems that this package is not longer in basic groovy installation?
How can I do XML processing in archetype groovy scripts?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Core Groovy no longer includes support for working with XML, JSON, etc.
Using the groovy-all artifact ID might do it for you.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
      <type>source</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```